# Schedule local Notification after app was closed for 7 days

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

It was quite a bit hard to enable `local notifications` for my application.

And yeah, I set up my project with a `local notification` witch I want to schedule after the app had been closed for **one** week. For example if the user opens the app on saturday 8th, the local notification should appear on the next saturday the 15th, but the time should changed. For example he/she closes the app at 8pm and I don't want to disturb them at 8pm next week so I want to display every notification at 6pm or something like that.

Now you know my problem and here is my code I'm using:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    //set day (saturday)

    [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:26] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:1] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2013] ;

    [componentsForReferenceDate setHour: 17] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMinute:30] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setSecond:00] ;

    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForReferenceDate];

    // Create the notification

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;


    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Du wirst vermisst! \nDeine App braucht dich, schreibe sie zu Ende!"] ;
    notification.alertAction = @"Zurückkehren";
    notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"] forKey:@"information"];
    notification.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
    notification.soundName = @"Appnotifisound.wav";
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;

}
```

I know that there have to be more methods for deleting the badge and the `didrecievenotification`, but I let them out because there are **not** important for this.

With this code I managed to schedule the notification on **every** saturday at **5:30pm** (Germany). But I wanted to schedule it only once, when the app had been closed for exactly **one** week. Is that somehow possible? I would be glad if someone could correct my code or give me a solution for this.

Best regards and thank you for reading this long post,

Noah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should unschedule previous notification.

```
for (UILocalNotification *lNotification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) 
    {
        if ([[lNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"information"] isEqualToString:@"Some information"])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:lNotification];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Set fire date by below way:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                     fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [componentsForReferenceDate setHour: 17] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMinute:30] ;
    [componentsForReferenceDate setSecond:00] ;

    NSDate *tempDate = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForReferenceDate];
    [componentsForReferenceDate release];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [comps setDay:7];
    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps
                                                               toDate:tempDate options:0]
    [comps release];
```

Comment: Those previous notification are canceled! Look in the first line of code in the method, or I'm getting something wrong?

Comment: You are canceling all local notifications. So I think, its same. Otherwise you can put it at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Why are you setting date components for day,month and year had coded? Its the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I had this set up before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204419/only-let-local-notification-appear-once and they told me to use this! But I want to display it seven days after it was closed at 6pm! Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit` is causing this. use:

```
notification.repeatInterval = 0;
```

This prevent repeating ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: I know but would this display the notification if the date was in the past?

Comment: @MasterRazer Yeah, sorry. Updated.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean! Look at the second line of code there is a row which says:     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
isn't that the solution?

Comment: :D Haha is this caused by apples iOS?

Comment: I can't imagine whats the matter here?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Swift 2.0** adaptation

Unscheduling the current notification

```
    for notifMe:AnyObject in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications!{
        let title = notifMe.userInfo["information"] as? String
        if title == "some information"{
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notifMe as! UILocalNotification)
        }
        }
```

Setting the date for the notification

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Year.union(NSCalendarUnit.Month).union(NSCalendarUnit.Day),fromDate: date)
    components.hour = 17
    components.minute = 30
    components.second = 00

    let tempDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    let comps = NSDateComponents()
    comps.day = 7
    let fireDateOfNotification = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(comps, toDate: tempDate, options:[])
```